# Homogeneous coordinates and perspective-correctness?

Tags: graphics, 3d, vulkan

Does the technique that vulkan uses (and I assume other graphics libraries too) to interpolate vertex attributes in a perspective-correct manner require that the vertex shader must normalize the homogenous camera-space vertex position (ie: divide through by the w-coordinate such that the w-coordinate is 1.0) prior to multiplication by a typical projection matrix of the form...

```
 g/s  0    0         0
  0   g    0         n
  0   0    f/(f-n)   -nf/(f-n)
  0   0    1         0
```

...in order for perspective-correctness to work properly?

Or, will perspective-correctness continue to work on any homogeneous vertex position in camera-space (with a w-coordinate other than 1.0)?

(I didn't completely follow the perspective-correctness math, so it is unclear which to me which is the case.)

**Update:**

In order to clarify terminology:

```
vec4 modelCoordinates = vec4(x_in, y_in, z_in, 1);
mat4 modelToWorld = ...;
vec4 worldCoordinates = modelToWorld * modelCoordinates;
mat4 worldToCamera = ...;
vec4 cameraCoordinates = worldToCamera * worldCoordinates;
mat4 cameraToProjection = ...;
vec4 clipCoordinates = cameraToProjection * cameraCoordinates;
output(clipCoordinates);
```

`cameraToProjection` is a matrix like the one shown in the question

The question is does `cameraCoordinates.w` have to be `1.0`?

And consequently the last row of both the `modelToWorld` and `worldToCamera` matricies have to be `0 0 0 1`?

Comment: "*The question is does cameraCoordinates.w have to be 1.0?*" It will be whatever your mathematics says that it needs to be. I don't understand your question. You're doing math to achieve some purpose. The numbers should be the ones that achieve that purpose. You can [mathematically do transformations in post-projective space](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Texturing/Tutorial%2017.html); that's mathematically legitimate and such matrices will not necessarily have a `W` of 1.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's not clear to me what you're not understanding.  Anyway, for anyone that does understand the question, I think I've concluded that yes W in cameraCoordinates has to be 1.0 for the usual projection matrix to work (ie homogeneous cameraCoordinates have to be in normal form in the shader).  `Z_camera` becomes `W_clip` and see "Basic Polygon Rasterization" in the Vulkan spec.  Associated datum for a fragment use barycentric coordinates based off framebuffer coordinates and the `W_clip`.  So I think unnormalized camera coordinates won't work.

Comment: I just linked you to an example of doing rotations in post-projection homogenous coordinates. So no, W does not "have to be" 1.0, and thinking that it does is hazardous to properly understanding the math behind this stuff.

Comment: @NicolBolas: As shown in the above code, the cameraCoordinates are multiplied by the given projection matrix and output from the vertex shader.  The question is do those cameraCoordinates have to be normalized (homogeneous coordinates with a W value of 1.0).  I'm not talking about post-projective transformations or anything else.

Comment: "*The question is do those cameraCoordinates have to be normalized*" "have to be" in order for what to happen? Why are you questioning whether your camera space is homogeneous or not? That is, why do you think that W *might not be 1*? Don't you control the inputs to this code?

Comment: And if you don't have control over those matrices, if you're writing a lower-level system where external users provide the transforms, then it's not your job to stop them if they put the wrong values into those matrices.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Have to be normalized in order for the vertex attribute interpolation in Vulkans polygon rasterization algorithm to continue to be perspective-correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see whether or not the camera coordinates need to be in normal form, let's represent the camera coordinates as multiples of `w`, so they are `(wx,wy,wz,w)`.

Multiplying through by the given projection matrix, we get the clip coordinates `(wxg/s, wyg, fwz/(f-n)-nfw/(f-n)), wz)`

Calculating the x-y framebuffer coordinates as per the fixed Vulkan formula we get `(P_x * xg/sz +O_x, P_y * Hgy/z + O_y)`.  Notice this does not depend on `w`, so the position in the framebuffer of a polygons verticies doesn't require the camera coordinates be in normal form.

Likewise calculation of the barycentric coordinates of fragments within a polygon only depends on `x,y` in framebuffer coordinates, and so is also independant of `w`.

However perspective-correct perspective interpolation of fragment attributes does depend on `W_clip` of the verticies as this is used in the formula given in the Vulkan spec.  As shown above `W_clip` is `wz` which does depend on `w` and scales with it, so we can conclude that camera coordinates must be in normal form (their `w` must be `1.0`)

Answer (score 2):

You have this exactly backwards. Doing the perspective divide in the shader is what *prevents* perspective-correct interpolation. The rasterizer *needs* the perspective information provided by the W component to do its job. With a W of 1, the interpolation is done in window space, without any regard to perspective.

Provide a clip-space coordinate to the output of your vertex processing stage, and let the system do what it exists to do.

---

> the vertex shader must normalize the homogenous camera-space vertex position (ie: divide through by the w-coordinate such that the w-coordinate is 1.0) prior to multiplication by a typical projection matrix of the form...

If your camera-space vertex position does not have a W of 1.0, then one of two things has happened:

1. You are deliberately operating in a post-projection world space or some similar construct. This is a perfectly valid thing to do, and the math for a camera space can be perfectly reasonable.
2. Your code is broken somewhere. That is, you *intend* for your world and camera space to be a normal, Euclidean, non-homogeneous space, but somehow the math didn't work out. Obviously, this is not a perfectly valid thing to do.

In both cases, dividing by W is the wrong thing to do. If your world space that you're placing a camera into is post-projection (such as [in this example](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Texturing/Tutorial%2017.html)), dividing by W will *break* your perspective-correct interpolation, as outlined above. If your code is broken, dividing by W will merely *mask* the actual problem; better to fix your code than to hide the bug, as it may crop up elsewhere.

Comment: I think you misread my question.  I am asking about the _camera-space coordinates_ before they are multiplied by the projection matrix to transform them to the clip-space coordinates that are output from the vertex shader.  Do the _camera-space coordinates_ need to have a W of 1 in order for the shown projection matrix to work properly?  My suspicious is that the answer is yes.

Comment: Update added to question.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos: I've added a section to the answer to more fully explain the problem.

Comment: Ok, so I think I see what you're not understanding.  A homogeneous coordinate is a 4D representation of a 3D point.  The mapping is (x,y,z,w) to (x/w,y/w,z/w).  So the two homogeneous points (2,4,8,2) and (3,6,12,3) both repesent the same 3D point, namely (1,2,4).  When W is 1 in a homogeneous point we say that it is normalized.  The question is do the cameraCoordinates have to be in such normal form prior to multiplication by the projection matrix for it to work, or will it work with unnormalized homogeneous points?  I think the answer is yes, it has to be normalized.

Comment: It depends on what your transforms are actually doing. A matrix is a matrix is a matrix, and what "works" or "doesn't work" depends on the *values in those matrices*.

Comment: Right and I gave the values of the matrix `cameraToProjection` in the question, and showed that the `cameraCoordinates` are multiplied by it and output from the vertex shader.  Vulkan is then performing fixed Polygon Rasterization with the output.  The question is will Vulkans polygon rasterization work with unnormalized `cameraCoordinates`.  I think the answer is no it wont.

Comment: Vulkan *does not see* "cameraCoordinates". You don't pass camera-space positions to Vulkan; by fiat, the positions you pass to Vulkan are in clip space. If you're passing camera-space positions *of any kind* to Vulkan, then either what you call "camera-space" actually is "clip-space" or your math is wrong. So it's not clear how Vulkan cares what is going on in your camera-space positions, since it never sees them.

Comment: The clip coordinates in most vulkan programs (and as specified in the question) are the result of the multiplication of a cameraToProjection matrix and the cameraCoordinates in the vertex shader.  Vulkan then does fixed processing of the output clip coordinates as described under chapter 24 & 25 of the vulkan spec.  Therefore, given a fixed cameraToProjection matrix, Vulkan does effectively "see" the cameraCoordinates, albeit indirectly, and does place constraints on the cameraCoordinates.  The question is about these constraints.

Comment: "*"see" the cameraCoordinates, albeit indirectly, and does place constraints on the cameraCoordinates*" No, it sees clip-space. Any "constraints" that Vulkan's treatment of clip-space applies to clip-space apply to camera-space depend *entirely* on what *exactly* is in your matrices. So I say again, if the camera-space position is not "normalized", there are only two possibilities: you *meant* for it to not be normalized, or you have a bug. The resolution for neither of these cases is to normalize the camera space position. You are wrong to think you should normalize your camera space position

Comment: I told you exactly what was in the matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226933/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-andrew-tomazos).